# Add filter unless it is being called under specific function

Tags: filters

I want to add a filter ... but not if it that filter is called by a specific function. Here's a simplified example:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt' );
function wp_trim_excerpt( $text ) {

    $text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );

    return $text;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );
function my_content_filter( $content ) {

    // my code that modifies $content

    return $content;

}
```

Is there any way to check if `my_content_filter` is being initiated by `wp_trim_excerpt` before running my code?

EDIT: The [core function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) `wp_trim_excerpt` is in play here, so I'd rather not alter the function if possible. Above I simplified it to the most pertinent part.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress only holds the `hooks` information in global `$wp_filter` so you can check if a hook is registered with some specified function or not. you can also use function [has_filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_filter).

But I guess you can not check that, it has been called or not on some specific execution point.

But you can do this with PHP using global variable.

Check this code

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'my_trim_excerpt' );
function my_trim_excerpt($text) {
    global $filter_applied;
    $filter_applied = true;

    $text = wp_trim_excerpt($text);

    return $text;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );
function my_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $filter_applied;

    if (isset($filter_applied) && $filter_applied === true) {
        //Your code when wp_trim_excerpt is already called.
    }

    //my code that modifies $content

    return $content;
}
```

Here I am using a global variable `$filter_applied` and modifying value on `wp_trim_excerpt` then checking it on `my_content_filter`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! Part of my problem is that a core function `wp_trim_excerpt` ([ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt)) is being used, so I can't edit it. (I should have clarified that above.) `$wp_filter` isn't providing enough info to differentiate.

Comment: Oh I missed that! Check the updated answer now. Hope it will help @AdamCapriola

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt' );
function wp_trim_excerpt( $text ) {

    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );
    $text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );

    return $text;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );
function my_content_filter( $content ) {

    // my code that modifies $content

    return $content;

}
```

I didn't want to directly edit the `wp_trim_excerpt` function because it's a core WordPress function (I simplified it for clarity here). However, I couldn't figure out any other great way to do this. So I removed the original `get_the_excerpt` filter that's in the WordPress core, then duplicated the function in my theme files, and made the edits then reapplied the filter.